# Matrix artihmetic in PHP?

Tags: php, matrix

Does anyone know of a PHP library that handles matrix multiplication, inversion, etc.?

Comment: I'm sure you fired up Google with "php matrix", what was the problem with the results?

Comment: I guess I felt like the results all seemed to be "some guy" who had developed his own matrix library, and I was looking for something a bit more widely tested.

Comment: RELATED [and closed] : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828237/is-there-a-good-php-library-for-vectors-and-matrices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the [Math_Matrix](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix) library. I haven't used it, but it seems to be fairly comprehensive, going beyond simple matrix arithmetic to also include things like calculating the determinant or solving systems of equations.

Answer (score 3):

There is a relatively recent library for [Linear Regression for PHP](http://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/regression-analysis-using-php/). This library does contain classes for matrix multiplication, and unit tests with 100% code coverage.