# port Matlab program to run on Apache server

Tags: php, matlab

I'm in the process of analyzing a large chunk of data in matlab. The data is userdata which is freely available and which I want to use to make recommendations for users using my Internet service.

My question is: **once I've written my algorithm in matlab what is the easiest/best way to integrate it into my php project /website?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Convert the algorithm to PHP code.

Comment: @GWW is PHP suited for matrix operations with large data set? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573674/looking-for-actively-maintained-matrix-math-library-for-php this link say otherwise, converting it to Python seems to be the accepted answer there. So maybe Python?

Comment: @Flying Swissman: Call matlab from PHP then?

Comment: @GWW I don't want it to depend on matlab.

Comment: Of course I don't know why you don't want to depend on matlab but if license etc is the problem, maybe [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) could be a good alternative for the server?

Comment: @Czechnology The license, yes. I have a student license atm, but I'm not sure how much longer for and I'm not sure I'm allowed to used in this way. Octave seems like a good idea. Is the language syntax similar to matlab? And would you suggest installing it on the server? (not an overkill?) -thanks

Comment: I'm stydying applied mathematics (TU Wien) and I've used Octave for a few semesters without much problems (so I didn't have to buy the student's license for matlab). Just plotting is a bit complicated and there are some minor differences in syntax (but usually it's matlab who's missing features, like do-until) but porting to octave syntax will be faster and easier than porting to python and php. Also the calculations will be much faster. Is it worth installing it? Well that depends on your project - how much calculations you have there and how often will they be executed.

Comment: On a sidenote - I haven't got into much advanced stuff with octave (been using it just in the first three or four semesters, then I needed easy plotting) so if you're using some advanced tools or commands, you might want to check out octave's docs first to see if it's supported (unless you can code it yourself).

Comment: The MATLAB runtime is redistributable.  You can compile standalone executables of your MATLAB code that depend on the redistributable runtime only.  This is so people can sell products that use MATLAB under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys. @Czechnology Octave def. sounds like possible solution. @rev_etrange I don't quite understand. What is redistributable runtime and what language would I compile the code to? C? -thanks

Comment: Another free alternative would be to use R for algorithms and rApache (a package found at http://crantastic.org) to interface with Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it really depends on what you are using Matlab for. In many ways, doing the same matrix transforms in PHP or Python would be a pain. Hence you were using Matlab. You can however keep everything in Matlab form by using the [Matlab Web Server](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1608.html).

Simply compile down to a binary that can be run on your server. See the examples supplied by Matworks.

Comment: the link is broken. any idea where it was moved to?