# merging two array in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays

```
$arr1=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'a'
        ),
    [1]=>Array
       (
         [0]=>'b'
       ),
     [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'c'
        ),
    [3]=>Array
       (
         [0]=>'d'
       ),
[4]=>Array
       (
         [0]=>'e'
       )
);
$arr2=array('1','2');
```

output should be

```
$arr3=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'a',
            [1]=>'1'

        ),
    [1]=>Array
       (
         [0]=>'b',
         [1]=>'2'
       ),
     [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'c',  
            [1]=>'1'

        ),
    [3]=>Array
       (
         [0]=>'d',
         [1]=>'2'
       ),
[4]=>Array
       (
         [0]=>'e',
         [1]=>'1'
       )
);
```

can someone please suggest me some solutions

Comment: Have you tried anything to get to your goal?

Comment: try with `array_merge` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix multiplication in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220655/matrix-multiplication-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version will allow `$arr2` to contain any number of values, should that be a requirement:

```
<?php

$arr1 = [
    ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'],
];

$arr2 = ['1', '2'];

// wrap the array in an ArrayIterator and then in an 
// InfiniteIterator - this allows you to continually
// loop over the array for as long as necessary

$iterator = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr2));
$iterator->rewind(); // start at the beginning

// loop over each element by reference
// push the current value in `$arr2` into 
// each element etc.
foreach ($arr1 as &$subArray) {
    $subArray[] = $iterator->current();
    $iterator->next();
}

print_r($arr1);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) and attach the first array as [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) and the second one as [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php), e.g.

```
<?php

    $arr1 = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"]];
    $arr2 = [1,2];
    $result = [];

    $mIt = new MultipleIterator();
    $mIt->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr1));
    $mIt->attachIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr2)));

    foreach($mIt as $v)
        $result[] = array_merge($v[0], [$v[1]]);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: Way ahead of me with `InfiniteIterator`!